# Bot Framework Web Chat - HTML Links and Markdown-it - Strips regular text when sending a link and text at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, botframework, markdown, chatbot

Having an issue where when an agent sends a message containing a link one of two things happens.

With no markdownit, a link written as "www.google.com" is delivered to the user as unrendered HTML:

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

If markdownit is added (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/10.0.0/markdown-it.js?ver=3.3.7) and html: true, linkify: true, are used, then links are correctly rendered and delivered to the user **BUT** all other text in the messages is deleted. No clue why...

So for example if the agent sends, "Click here: www.google.com"
The user receives, just a clickable link: www.google.com

Not familiar with really any of this stuff, but I'm rather clueless why it's stripping the regular text, but sending links fine.

My setup in part:

```
const markdownIt = window.markdownit({ html: true, linkify: true, typographer: false });

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    renderMarkdown: markdownIt.render.bind(markdownIt),
    styleOptions: {
       hideUploadButton: true
    },
    username: 'Web User',
    locale: $locale,
    store
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);

document.querySelector('#webchat').focus();
```

Also had it like this:

```
renderMarkdown: text => markdownIt.render(text),
```

Any ideas why it's stripping text? I tried toggling html false, linkify true and vice versa, as well as the typographer option, but no combo produced the desired results. LInks can be sent, and text can be sent fine- but not combined. Thanks in advance~

Used this as some reference: [botframework web chat V4 build and generate custom CSS and JS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387730/botframework-web-chat-v4-build-and-generate-custom-css-and-js-file)

Table of interaction:

[image: Table of interaction:]

Comment: I think we could use some more context here. It looks like you're using Web Chat and the Microsoft Bot Framework, so the title should probably say "Bot Framework Web Chat" instead of "Chatbot" because this isn't a generic chat bot problem. We need to determine if Web Chat is not receiving the correct text or if it is receiving the correct text and just isn't rendering it correctly. Is the agent also using Web Chat? If the agent sends "Click here: www.google.com" does it render as `Click here: <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>` without Markdown enabled? What if the user sends a link?

Comment: Hi Kyle- I've updated the title per your suggestion.

The agent is not using web chat. I believe they are using USD, but I'm blanking on what that stands for...

I will conduct the test above and get back to you- 

What I do know off hand is that messages that are coming directly from the Bot, such as the welcome messages are correctly sending text and URLs- with MarkDown enabled.

If I tell the bot my name is www.google.com, it renders it correctly when addressing me.

As a user links do not render.

When the live agent sends URLs, they render, but all other text is stripped out.

Comment: USD = Unified Service Desk

Also, the links render fine from the bot with Markdown disabled, too, btw.

Comment: What do you mean by "As a user links do not render"? Do you mean text that the user sends to the bot doesn't get converted to hyperlinks? Perhaps you should edit your question to contain some kind of table that contains all the situations you're describing because it seems kind of hard to follow right now. One axis would be Markdown enabled vs disabled and the other axis would be user-to-bot messages vs bot-to-user messages vs agent-to-user messages, and each cell would explain what's happening in that situation to the link text and non-link text.

Comment: "Do you mean text that the user sends to the bot doesn't get converted to hyperlinks? " 

Precisely.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think it's pretty clear at this point that the problem is the way USD is delivering hypertext to Web Chat. If you run your bot locally and test in Emulator then not only will you be able to debug the bot by stepping through the code but also you'll be able to see the exact activities that the client is receiving by looking at the Emulator logs. Assuming your agent communicates with the user by going through the bot, you can also see the activities in the bot while debugging. You may need to use a tunneling service like ngrok for the agent to reach the local bot

Comment: Thanks Kyle- I will post back if I find out some more info

Comment: Did you do any testing yet?